# Realation between determinant and minimum eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

For all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, let $P(k)\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be positive semidefinite. Assume $P(k)$ is bounded. Can we prove or disprove by counterexample that
\begin{equation}
 \det P(k)\to 0 \text{ as } k\to \infty \iff \lambda_\min\big(P(k)\big)\to 0 \text{ as } k\to \infty.
\end{equation}

I know that if $P(k)$ was unbounded then something like $P(k)=\left[\begin{array}{cc}1/k&0\\0&k\end{array}\right]$ would be a counterexample.

Thanks

Comment: “iff” can be symbolically replaced in MathJax with `\iff`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can prove this **is** in fact that case.  In particular, let $\|\cdot\|$ denote any choice of matrix norm (such as $\|A\| = \sqrt{\operatorname{tr}(A^TA)}$).  We note that all eiegnvalues of $P(k)$ satisfy $|\lambda| \leq \|P(k)\|$.  Because $P(k)$ is bounded, there is an $M>0$ such that $\|P(k)\| \leq M$ for all $k$.
Thus, we have
$$
0 \leq \left|\det(P(k))\right| = |\lambda_1| \cdot |\lambda_2|\cdots |\lambda_n| \leq |\lambda_{\min}(P(k))| \cdot \|P(k)\|^{n-1} \leq M^{n-1} \cdot |\lambda_{\min}(P(k))|
$$
So, $\lambda_{\min}(P(k)) \to 0 \implies \det(P(k)) \to 0$.

---

For the converse: suppose that $\det(P(k)) \to 0$.  Note that $\left|\det(P(k))\right| \geq |\lambda_{\min}(P(k))|^n$, which is to say that
$$
0 \leq |\lambda_{\min}(P(k))| \leq \left|\det(P(k))\right|^{1/n}
$$
The conclusion follows.

Comment: Thanks. Can you modify this to cover iff?

Comment: @Mohkam7 please note for the future that changing your question after someone answered it is frowned upon.  I'm not sure; thinking about it.

Comment: Sorry. I guess I just edited the question while you were typing the answer.

Comment: See my latest edit.

Comment: By the way: I've been assuming that $\lambda_{\min}$ refers to the smallest eigenvalue *in absolute value*, which I suppose isn't necessarily clear from your question.

Comment: That's right. I can make P(k) positive semidedfinite if you don't mind

Comment: @Mohkam7 I suppose that doesn't really change anything; go ahead.

Comment: For the converse proof, $k$ and $1/k$ in the powers should be $n$ and $1/n$.

Comment: @Mohkam7 whoops! Yes, that's what I meant